# How can I separate a double digit to two single digits with python? e.g. 15 -> 1, 5

Tags: python

```
def plus_cycles():
  n = int(input("Write here the number that you want. (1~99)\n"))
  while True:
    if n < 10:
      a = "n" + "0"
```

In this code, I want a to be separated with two single digits. e.g. 15 -> 1, 5 or [1, 5]

Comment: The code seems irrelevant to the actual question. What have you actually tried to do to separate the digits?

Comment: `"n"` is the literal string `"n"`, which isn't connected to the variable `n`. You can do `str(n)` or use an f-string.

Comment: Mad Physicist, oh I'm sorry. I didn't explain about what i'm making. I'm making a addition cycles which repeat addition until n comes back.

Comment: So plz just let me know how to separate a double digits to two single digits.

Answer (score 0):

The `divmod()` method takes two numbers and returns a pair of numbers (a tuple) consisting of their quotient and remainder. For integers, the result is the same as `(a // b, a % b)`.

```
>>>> divmod(15, 10)
(1, 5)
>>> 15 // 10
1
>>> 15 % 10
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could do something like this:

```
>>> intToList = lambda number : [int(i) for i in list(str(number))]
>>> intToList(15)
[1, 5]
```

`list(str(15))` Will return a List of Chars like:

```
>>> list(str(15))
['1', '5']
```

So we iterate through them with a for loop to turn them back ino integers.

Comment: It's an amazing answer, thanks. However, I cannot understand "lambda number"....What does lambda mean?

Comment: A lambda function is a small anonymous function. A lambda function can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression. Like a "one liner function". The `number` is the argument the function will take in this example.